# Scrolling is disabled all of a sudden in terminal

Tags: terminal, scrolling, konsole

Sometimes I use the terminal (konsole) and all of a sudden the behaviour when mouse scrolling goes from scrolling through past output to scrolling through the history on the command prompt, and there is no way to see the past output anymore. (The scrollbar is still there but it is as if there were no past output)

Since it only happens sometimes, and if I open a new subwindow it defaults back to scrolling through past output, I am guessing I am inadvertently hitting some shortcut that toggles between these modes, but I can't find out which shortcut it is.

How can I get out of this weird scrolling through history mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps you ran a subshell from an editor, and it left the terminal in the alternate screen.  You can test that by

```
tput rmcup
```

which would return to the normal display.

While in the alternate screen, some terminals may override the scroll-wheel action by sending up/down cursor escapes.

Answer (score 4):

The `reset` command helped me in this case

Comment: Hmm. Yeah this worked but it also erased the older commands I was trying to see in the first place, so this might not be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If `tput rmcup` is difficult to remember, you can execute the tool again (or any other one like `less`, `vim`...) and terminate it the proper way. This will terminate the cursor addressing mode as well.

Further details on https://askubuntu.com/a/123296/29914

Answer (score 0):

If `tput rmcup` won't work then try closing all the terminals and then use new terminals.